# Why is the animation not showing and is slowing down the rest?

Tags: java, javafx

The animation isn't showing on the Pane background and it slows down the other animation already present. I pass on the Pane background as a parameter so I don't know maybe that is the cause but I have other methods doing that and it's not causing any problems.

```
public static void fireAnimation(Pane animatedBackground) {
        
        
        AnimationTimer animationTimer = new AnimationTimer(){
            @Override
            public void handle (long now){
                
                listFireParticles.addAll(addFireParticles(200,200));
                for(Iterator<FireParticles> iteratorFirePart = listFireParticles.iterator(); iteratorFirePart.hasNext();){
                    
                    FireParticles fireParticle = iteratorFirePart.next(); 
                    fireParticle.particlesUpdate();
                    
                    if(!fireParticle.isAlive()){
                        iteratorFirePart.remove();
                        continue; 
                    }
                    
                    fireParticle.render(graphicsContext);
                }
                
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas (400, 400); 
                graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(); 
                animatedBackground.getChildren().add(canvas); 
            }
        };
        animationTimer.start();
                System.out.println("ANIMATION");
        }
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new canvas for each animation frame, rather than reusing an existing one.

1. You take a `Pane` and you add a new `Canvas` to it.
2. You do this an `AnimationTimer` `handle` method.
3. The timer method is called each pulse.
4. Be default, JavaFX generates a pulse sixty times a second.
5. In one second, your pane will contain sixty canvases.
6. In a minute there will be 3600 canvases.
7. In a day there will be five million one hundred and eighty four thousand canvases.
8. At some point before that, something is going to slow down and break.

**FAQ**

> How would I make the canvas stop being created so many times? I can't figure it out.

1. Remove the lines which create a canvas and add it to the scene graph from the animation timer `handle` method.
2. Create the canvas and add it to the scene graph (e.g. a pane) only once, outside of the `handle` method.
3. Store a reference to the canvas and access the reference in the `handle` method.

You likely have other issues in code not shown, so don't expect a simple fix as outlined above to just make your application work as you expect.

Perhaps something roughly like this:

```
final int W = 200;
final in  H = 200;
List<FireParticle> fireParticles = createFireParticles(W, H);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas (W, H); 
animatedBackground.getChildren().add(canvas); 

AnimationTimer animationTimer = new AnimationTimer() {
    @Override
    public void handle (long now){   
        GraphicsContext2D graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(); 
        graphicsContext.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

        if (fireParticles.isEmpty()) {
            this.stop();
            animatedBackground.getChildren().remove(canvas); 
            return;
        }
     
        for (Iterator<FireParticle> iteratorFirePart = fireParticles.iterator(); iteratorFirePart.hasNext();) {                
            FireParticle fireParticle = iteratorFirePart.next(); 
            fireParticle.particlesUpdate();
            
            if (!fireParticle.isAlive()){
                iteratorFirePart.remove();
                continue; 
            }
            
            fireParticle.render(graphicsContext);
        }        
    }
};

animationTimer.start();
```

**Important**: the above code is indicative only.  I make no assertion it will exhibit the behaviour you wish.  It is untested and won't work stand-alone, I didn't even try to compile it.  Without the requested minimal example, that is the best that can be provided.

Comment: Thank you.How would I make the canvas stop being created so many times? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @lola I edited the question to add info on managing the canvas instances.  It is just an example, you may need to do something a bit different to implement the functionality you require in your app.